# Angular 7: Post request always send a null body

Tags: angular, http, angular7, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to understand this issue i had for days now, so i want to send a post request with username and password using angular 7 to a nodejs rest api for authentication but it sends an empty body here is the login method in authservice.ts:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {

        let httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accepts': 'application/json'
            })
        };
        return this.http.post<any>(
            `${this.HOST_DOMAINE}/bo/api/authenticate`,
            {
                'username': username,
                'password': password
            },
            httpOptions
        );

    }
```

and here is the method for sending it in auth.component.ts:

```
signin() {

        this.loading = true;
        this.submitted = true;
        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            this.loading = false;
            return;
        }

        this._authService.login(
            this.loginForm.controls.username.value,
            this.loginForm.controls.password.value)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data['done'])
                        this._router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                    else {
                        this.showAlert('alertSignin');
                        this._alertService.error(data['msg'] + "");
                        this.loading = false;
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.showAlert('alertSignin');
                    this._alertService.error(error.message);
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            );
    }
```

I was searching for solution but everything i tried doesn't work and i don't know what did i miss here.
Note: I'm a beginner

Comment: this looks ok, please add the rest function from nodejs api

Comment: Check the networks tab or any tool to visualize the payload of your request. Most likely the body is sent.

Comment: Looks fine, try to debug your code on both server & client

Comment: last debug i did body displayed like this {} means its empty the request is sent but its empty anyways

Comment: Could there be something wrong with your form? Are the user and password passed into the method? How is your form defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is facing the same issue here is a temp solution!
So i found out that it was a problem of cross origin here is a work around it:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {

        let httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            }),
            params: new HttpParams()
                .set("username", username)
                .set("password", password),
            withCredentials: true
        };
        return this.http.post<any>(
            `${this.HOST_DOMAINE}/bo/api/authenticate`,
            null,
            httpOptions
        );

    }
```

I set the parameters in http header params with credentials as 'include' and replace content type from json to form-urlencoded
in nodejs express middleware i allowed cross origin here is the snippet:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.get('origin'));
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

it worked but still it needs test on the origin