# Body Always null or Wrong format in Angular

Tags: angular, axios

i have problem i should solve. i dont get it where is my fault. i already followed tutorial, i tried solution in stackoverflow but no solution is working.

so, i want send Post with body, it should be JSON (i tried my endpoint with postman it's perfect).
every time i send it, it always null or the format is wrong,

here is my code.

```
const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'https://us-central1-roamx-6c177.cloudfunctions.net',
      timeout: 1000,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:4200'}
    });

instance({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/SBpaymidrove',
        data: {a: "b", c: 2}
      }).then(response => console.log(response));
```

if I run, the body is null,

but if i change header to

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

it become like this (log in firebase)

```
method: 'POST',
uri: 'https://api.sandbox.midtrans.com/v2/charge',
  body: { '{"a":"b","c":2}': '' },
  headers: 
   { Accept: 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  json: true }
```

i dont understand, i tried these solution.
[Angular 7: Post request always send a null body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552540/angular-7-post-request-always-send-a-null-body)
and
[Angular - calling web api HttpPost with FromBody string - body is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54078776/angular-calling-web-api-httppost-with-frombody-string-body-is-always-null)
i tried using http/common from angular too, but it have same result.

neither works. please help.

EDIT
here if I using http from angular.

```
this.header = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

this.http.post<DetailTransaction>('https://us-central1-***********.cloudfunctions.net/SBpaymidrove',
     {a: "b", c: 2}, {headers: this.header, withCredentials: true})
     .subscribe(
     data  => {
     console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
     },
     error  => {
     console.log("Error", error);
     }
);
```

Comment: What are your reasons for using axios instead of the Angular http client? Just curious :)

Comment: @KurtHamilton no no, i am big fans of angular http client, its perfect. just in my case, i already tried it and fail, so i tried other library if it will solve my problem. but it is not solved. would you like i post using anguar http too? i will provide it.

Comment: I would say there's a 0.01% that the Angular `HttpClient` is at fault here :) You should add what you've tried with `HttpClient`, and also what you submit in Postman. That should highlight where the issue is

Comment: @KurtHamilton hello, i already add eith angular http. please help me sir. thankyou.

Comment: Can you also show what `detailTrx` is and what `baseUrl` is?

Comment: sorry, i edit it. i make it bare, not a variable. @KurtHamilton

Comment: And what's the error you are receiving?

Comment: @KurtHamilton this is the error.

`body: { 'a: "b", c: 2': '' },
  headers: 
   { Accept: 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  json: true }`

teh format is not json when i got it in my back end.